# Problem with connection string to SQL express

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I get this error message when i try to using sql express:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named
>   database for file
>   C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\MyProject\MyWeb\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

My connection string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

I can't finde out what the problem is. The database exist, it work when i trying to debbug. but not when i run IIS7 at localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with this two links:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803211949/http://geekswithblogs.net/ProjectLawson/archive/2009/05/05/iis-system.web.aspnethostingpermission-exception-on-windows-7-rc.aspx)

http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/fix-error-Failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-SQL-Server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-the-process-for-the-user-instance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that IIS7 is running under a different user account that doesn't have both read and write access to the directory and mdf file.

Comment: The are same user account at the web folder and on the app_data folder

Comment: The IIS user obvoiusly has read access then, but does it have write access?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any database named MyDatabase or database who has create MyDatabase.mdf as data file in your sql express ?

Comment: The database exist in the folder

Comment: i am just curious whether you have any file named MyDatabase.mdf in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data" folder ?

Comment: Not in that folder, in the app_data folder for my web project

Comment: Do you have given permission APP_Data folder for NETWORK_SERVICE user ?

Comment: Can you check the link below 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx

Check sections named File Access and SQL Server and confirm if your IIS and Local SQL Server has enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add read/write premissions for IUSR to the folder where the database is;

Best Regards!!!

Comment: Well, if it allready have that? And it not working with that?

Comment: Try this, gives you some steps to solve the issue;
http://www.aspspider.com/resources/Resource170.aspx
Also give permission to NETWORK SERVICE on that folder.-