# Visual Studio 2017 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException An attempt to attach an auto-named database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, exception, visual-studio-2017

**Don't Mark it as Duplicate or On Hold.**
I have tried all the solutions given in these answers here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566036/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-database1-mdf-failed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509441/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-error) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012701/how-to-connect-sql-server-express-database-to-vs-2017) and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367244/problem-with-connection-string-to-sql-express).  Following is my piece of code.

```
  string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='D:\Codes\Test\MyDataBase.mdf';Integrated Security=True;";
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
  string query = "select * from StudentInfo";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

  con.Open();   //Exception Appears Here...

  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if (dr.HasRows)
  {
      while (dr.Read())
      {
           Console.WriteLine(dr[0] + "  " + dr[1] + "   " + dr[2] + "  " + dr[3]);
       }
  }
  con.Close();
```

Following Exception appears when I open the connection:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file MyDataBase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'

I added a Service-Based Database in my Project made in **Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.6.4**. I have tried many solutions from different websites too , Does its solution really exits? or we have to make a new project and start from scratch again?

Comment: If it's a local database, why do u need to add it as a `Service-Based Database` ??

Comment: [This documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#initialcatalog) suggests that the lack of an initial catalog is causing the path to be used as the database name, and your localdb already has an instance of this. Try adding `Initial Catalog=this-is-a-test;` to the connection string and see if that alleviates the error, then name it something more appropriate for your application.

Comment: @JonathonChase I tried Initial Catalog=this-is-a-test; gives me another exception.  **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:  'Cannot attach the file 'D:\Test\MyDataBase.mdf' as database 'this-is-a-test'.'**

Comment: Have you tried removing the single-quotes from your connection string?

Comment: @zackraiyan  Because in VS2017 Test->Right Click->Add->Data , Only `Service-Based DataBase` option is available. Other option includes DataSet , ADO.net Entity Data Model.

Comment: just change ur connectionstring as follows `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                          AttachDbFilename=D:\Codes\Test\MyDataBase.mdf
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Connect Timeout=30;
                          User Instance=True"`

Comment: @JonathonChase Yes I have tried removing single quotes but still the same exception appears.

Comment: @zackraiyan  I have tried this `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=D:\Codes\Test\MyDataBase.mdf; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30; User Instance=True"`    but it gives me another exception  **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.'**

Comment: That string is missing the semicolon between the AttachDbFilename section and the Integrated Security section.

Comment: just remove `user interface=true`

Comment: @JonathonChase  I mistakenly missed the semicolon but its written in my project.

Comment: @zackraiyan Tried removing `user interface=true` , the same exception appears which I have asked in the question.

Comment: Is stopping/deleting/creating/starting the localdb an option?

Comment: @JonathonChase  If we create a new project with a new Db, then it will work but creating whole database with multiple tables plus if you are having a mvc  or a n-tier architecture will be much time consuming :-( .

Comment: hey waitt.....is ur visual studio is of express  version ?

Comment: @zackraiyan  Nope, its **Visual Studio 2017 Community  Version 15.6.4**,  downloaded from here [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15).

Comment: Given that you have tried many of the common workarounds, I think that your error is most likely tied to the first part of the error, do you have another attached database Named MyDatabase by chance?

Comment: @MitchelSellers  I have already checked the **Sql Server Folder located in Program Files in C Disk**. There's no similar Database.

Comment: **I think its solution not exists after all.**